# Evaluate $\cos(z)$, given that $z = i \log(2+\sqrt{3})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

**Q. Evaluate $\cos(z)$, given that $z = i \log(2+\sqrt{3})$**

I did it in 2 ways, and the results do not match.

**Method 1**

Multiply both sides by $i^3$, we get

$$-iz = \log(2+\sqrt{3})$$ and so,

$$2+\sqrt{3} = e^{-iz} = \cos(z) - i \sin(z)$$

from which we have $\cos(z)= 2+\sqrt{3}$ ?!

**Method 2**

I added $i\log(2-\sqrt{3})$ both sides, to get:

$$i\log(2-\sqrt{3})+z=i\log(4)$$

from which we have, following similar procedure, $\cos(z) = 2-\sqrt{3}$, which fortunately is $< 1$

What actually is happening? And is $\cos(z)$ even defined for complex number $z$?

Comment: $\cos(z)$ is real, but $\sin(z)$ isn't. $\sin(z)=i\sqrt3$.

Comment: But $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ lie in -1 to 1 range, even in graphs. What am I not getting?

Comment: @GitGud Yes! Ill change it now. Thanks!

Comment: @samjoe But also we had $(2+\sqrt{3})\times(2 - \sqrt{3}) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: For complex $z$, we simply have $$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} \text{   and   } \sin z=\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Comment: But why is my approach incorrect?

Comment: @samjoe This procedure is not right simply because as Max said, sin z and cos z need not be real. Also, see [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Functions_of_complex_variables).

Comment: That means they can be complex valued? Thanks but that is surprising! We were never told that!

Answer (score 3):

Both methods are not quite correct as $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ **need not be real**. You can evaluate $\cos( z)$ using the formula:

$$\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

From this you have:
$$\cos(z)=\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}+\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}=2$$

Comment: Well I don't know how to deal with it. I simply take everything in principle branch. If you wish to edit the post and add about it I'd be grateful!

Comment: Why are $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ not real? They always lie in $[-1,1]$ only?

Comment: @MaxPayne Nevermind, I just realised the argument in the logarithm is actually a real number, so what I said, even though it is valid, it is unnecessary here.