# Is Euler's formula valid for complex arguments

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I found this question here :

[Evaluate $\cos(z)$, given that $z = i \log(2+\sqrt{3})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077011/evaluate-cosz-given-that-z-i-log2-sqrt3)

It says that -
$$e^{-iz} = \cos(z) - i \sin(z)$$
isn't necessarily true because $$\sin z$$ is imaginary (for the particular value of z in the link). But, the proof of Euler's formula using Maclaurin series suggests that it should be valid for complex arguments too. What am I missing?

Comment: Verbatim from the wiki article on Euler's formula: *The original proof is based on the Taylor series expansions of the exponential function $e^z$ (where $z$ is a complex number) and of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ for real numbers $x$ (see below). In fact, the same proof shows that Euler's formula is even valid for all complex numbers $x$.*  I think you will find it valuable to exercise looking for your answers before finding them... sometimes the answers are just lying around, because, believe it or not, other people have asked the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't say that $$e^{iz}=\cos(iz)-i\sin(iz)$$is not necessarily true! It *is* true. What it says in that other answer is that $\cos(iz)$ is not necessarily the real part of $e^{iz}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing nothing: for *every* complex number $z$, $e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z$.

Comment: Strange how I realised that sin z being i√3 will mean that the real part of the LHS doesn't have to equal the cosine of the argument as soon as I read your answer. I suppose the cosine of a purely imaginary number being real is as surprising as the fact that i raised to i is real.